# PHP, PDO, SQLite INNER JOIN Statement And Variable

Tags: php, pdo, sqlite, inner-join

I need to do a PHP PDO call to my db with an INNER JOIN and WHERE clause.

In navicat GUI this statement is running fine and i can see the results. The problem come out lather in php environment about string concatenation.

I would like to format this request so that it can be digested by php:

```
SELECT * FROM tsourcetb as T INNER JOIN users as U ON U.username = T.username WHERE U.username = $username AND T.username = $username;
```

what I tried to do

```
$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tsourcetb as T INNER JOIN users as U ON U.username = T.username WHERE U.username = $username AND T.username = $username");
```

the return is an error indicating that there is no table with the variable name. Basically it takes the variable as the name of the table the return is an error indicating that there is no table with the variable name. Basically it takes the variable as the table name and not the table name as it should like (SELECT * FROM $username) jumping out the first part of statement).

The intent is to have all the records of table A where the username field is = to the username field of table B with value passed from a variable.
Thank for any suggestion to achieve my goal.

UPDATE

php is magic need to try and retray. At the end tish one help  me to goal:

```
$username = ($_POST['username']);
$password = ($_POST['password']);

$statement = $db->prepare('SELECT p.* FROM `tsourcetb` as p LEFT JOIN    `users`as s ON p.username = s.username WHERE s.username = :username;');
$statement->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->execute();
```

/* look here -> $statement->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) */

```
$array_select = $statement->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($array_select, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tsourcetb as T INNER JOIN users as U ON U.username = T.username WHERE U.username = :username AND T.username = :username");
$stmt->bindValue(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```

You need to bind a value with prepared statement:

Source: [Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: i get an error:  Call to undefined method PDO::bindValue()

Comment: @sundsx You are right, I made a mistake  changed it

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind parameters when you are making an dynamic query with PDO.
Change this in your query.

```
$username -> :username
```

And before you make the call

```
$yourQueryObj->bindValue(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

That's why prepared statments are safer than regular variables as you assign it's type before it's sent for query.

You can read about it here
http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php

You should be able also execute with array of parameters after preparing like that :

```
$sth = execute(array(':username'=> $username));
```

Comment: Call to undefined method PDO::bindParam()

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php


$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `tsourcetb` as T INNER JOIN users as U ON U.username = T.username WHERE U.username = ?  AND T.username = ? ");
$sth->execute([$username,$username]);
$results = $sth->fetchall();


?>
```

wrapper your table name with backticks and also use placeholders

Comment: hi and thanks for time. I have 2 table and in you example only one is backticksed. Anyway nothing happens no results was valorized